# gwt form: request send and arrived, but no response in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, formpanel

I must be missing something simple, but I'm stuck.
I created a FormPanel in gwt that, according to firebug sends the request.
the link works, as I copied the requestlink from firebug and tried it natively in a browser window.
Yes, client and server host are the same --> localhost.
But the answer doesn't arrive at gwt. Not even the client browser - firebug shows no result eighter.

This is my little form:

```
    Button form = new Button ("SendForm", new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            logger.log(Level.FINER, "Creating SubmitForm...");

            TextBox cmd = new TextBox();
            cmd.setName("cmd");
            cmd.setText("GetMenuitemList");

            Button sendbutton = new Button("Senden");
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Creating grid...");
            Grid grid = new Grid(1, 2);
            grid.setWidget(0, 0, new  Label("Command"));
            grid.setWidget(0, 1, cmd);

            VerticalPanel vPan = new VerticalPanel();
            //vPan.add(grid);
            vPan.add(sendbutton);

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Creating FormPanel...");
            final FormPanel formPan = new FormPanel();
            formPan.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
            formPan.setAction(RequestHelper.getLink("Menu.php"));

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Binding Send button...");
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Binding SubmitHandler...");
            formPan.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
                    OptionPane.showMessageDialog("Form submit", event.toDebugString(), MessageType.INFO, true);
                }
            });

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Binding SubmitCompleteHandler...");
            formPan.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                    OptionPane.showMessageDialog("Form SubmitComplete", event.toDebugString(), MessageType.INFO, true);
                }
            });

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Adding grid to formpan...");
            formPan.add(grid);
            formPan.add(vPan);

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Creating DialogBox...");
            final DialogBox box = OptionPane.createClosableBox("TestForm", true);

            sendbutton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    formPan.submit();
                    box.hide();
                }
            });

            box.add(formPan);
            box.center();
        }
    });
```

The expected answer looks like this:

```
{"sessionid":"6dbqibo25e0bn46fldqh37psj5","data":[{"title":"Start","Controller":"Start","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Startseite, Begr\u00fc\u00dfung","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Register","Controller":"Person","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Neue Benutzer registrieren","prefetch":"0"},{"title":"Daten","Controller":"Contact","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Die eigenen Daten bearbeiten","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Teilnehmerlisten","Controller":"Lists","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Listen der registrierten Benutzer","prefetch":"0"},{"title":"Suche","Controller":"Search","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Namenssuche nach Benutzer mit Kontaktm\u00f6glichkeit","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Kalender","Controller":"Calendar","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Termine","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Newsletter","Controller":"Newsletter","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Verschicken von Newslettern","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Wettk\u00e4mpfer","Controller":"Competitor","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Zugriff auf Wettk\u00e4mpfer","prefetch":"1"},{"title":"Upload","Controller":"Upload","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Bilder, Videos o.\u00e4. hochladen","prefetch":"0"},{"title":"Administration","Controller":"Admin","Action":"Index","tooltip":"Datenbankfunktionen und Benutzerrechte","prefetch":"1"}]}
```

So, what is going wrong here?

BTW, I'll use this technique for a login form. I read, its better to do this in a form than via RequestBuilder (that worked already). File upload will come later, so the form question needs an answer in any case...

Thank you in advance.
Markus

Edit: ok, I tested on Chromium, Konqueror and Opera also - the code works. It's just firefox. Ideas to get it going with firefox?
I'm a total newby in eclipse and gwt... maybe some compiler option?

Comment: If Firebug doesn't show a response, then check your server. If it does, check its console for possible errors; also check the origin: same server is not enough, you also need same scheme (http vs. https) and port! Finally, the server **must** answer with a `text/html` response for the submit-complete event to fire.

Comment: Webadress: http://localhost/~markus/gwt2/ 
request: http://localhost/~markus/gwt2/php/Menu.php?cmd=GetMenuitemList
Of cause no errors on the console...

What can I check the server for?
The answer is a json string, is that a problem?

Comment: Do you reply with `Content-Type: text/html`? Firebug really tells you it didn't see a response?

Comment: Funny thing: in Chromium it works...
Yes, firebug says, it receives 0Byte... and is pending...

I dont give a content type -it's just plain json.. wrong? I'll post an example answer in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found and solved the problem myself: after the form.submit was executed, I hid the form Panel.
That is not allowed as javadoc says:

> The FormPanel must not be detached (i.e. removed from its parent or otherwise disconnected from a RootPanel) until the submission is complete. Otherwise, notification of submission will fail.